# Minimal functionality for a custom iterator derived non-publicly from an STL iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, iterator

Please consider the following code, where an inline iterator class is defined for a wrapper class around an `std::vector`:

```cpp
class Vector
{
public:
    using VectorIt = std::vector<int>::const_iterator;

    class iterator: protected VectorIt
    {
    public:
        iterator(const VectorIt& it): VectorIt(it) { }

        using VectorIt::operator*;
        using VectorIt::operator->;
    };

    iterator begin() const { return iterator(v.cbegin()); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(v.cend()); }

private:
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
};
```

I would like to control access to functionality provided by the STL iterator base class of the custom iterator, hence the protected inheritance. When I use this list in a range-for loop as follows:

```
for (auto i : Vector{}) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
```

I am greeted with the following error (GCC 5.3.0):

> ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >’ is an
>   inaccessible base of ‘Vector::iterator’

What is the minimal functionality of the underlying `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` that I need to expose such that `Vector::iterator` can be used in the range-based for loop shown above?

Comment: This whole design is completely off the mark. `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` may well be simply `const int *` and then your entire code explodes.

Comment: whats wrong with just `typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator iterator;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is expressed through the traditional [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) like follows:

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

can be considered to expand to

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr;
            __begin != __end; ++__begin) {

        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement
    }
}
```

where some unique identifiers are used instead of `__range`, `__begin` and `__end`, so that no identifier from the enclosing scope is hidden.

This means that the iterator type must support the following operations:

- `!=`
- `++` (preincrement)
- `*` (dereference)